# Aligning divs in a row without using float

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a 2x2 grid structure using 4 divs wrapped inside a `.container` without using `float` like so:

```
[ ][ ]
[ ][ ]
```

However when I try to do so I am instead experiencing this:

```
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
```

The `.box`es need to be 50% height and width with no border or margins.
This is the code I am using to try and achieve this:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
  width:600px;
  height:700px;
  position:relative;
}
.box{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  background:red;
}
```

Here is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0f4kcmom/2/) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make change in your html like:

```
<div class="box"></div><!--
--><div class="box"></div><!--
--><div class="box"></div><!--
--><div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Or

```
<div class="container">
<div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Remove space between box div as you are using `display:inline-block`

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0f4kcmom/3/)**

**[More info](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)**

Comment: Thank you for your thorough and well explained answer. I could definitely use this. However it seems like this is a bit of a hack? Is there a more 'legit' way of doing this do you know?

Comment: @Gorg No this is not hack. This is how inline-block working.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably look into using css3's [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) approach, which will solve the issues you're having.

Using your example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box">Box 4</div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 50%;
  min-height: 250px; // for example, to give a minimum height
}
.box {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  background: green;
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
}
.box:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

Much cleaner and easier than other solutions. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbbrwcky/48p3zsrg/1/) link here.

Comment: Thank you for providing this alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set font-size:0 on your container to remove white-space. Or remove white-space in your code.

If you wan't to know more about this read this article

https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

```css
.container{
  width:600px;
  height:700px;
  position:relative;
  font-size: 0;
}
.box{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight into the use of font-size: 0; an interesting way of keeping this 'clean'

Answer (score 1):

This problem may happen because you have whitespaces between each box, try this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="box"></div><!--
--><div class="box"></div><!--
--><div class="box"></div><!--
--><div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

I haven't tried to do it but it should get rid of the whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container{
  width:600px;
  height:700px;
  position:relative;
  
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.row{
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:row;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}
.box{
  background-color:red;
  height:50%;
  width:50%;
  border:1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
</div>


</div>
```

Using **flex** , you can flexibly handle all these kind of things with ease.
 
More info on flex [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3u4c8h4/1/) for the solution to your problem.

And

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3u4c8h4/2/) for more responsive design .